# How to write an IPERF Android application

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, adb, iperf

I want to create an "iperf 3" Android application.

How can I do it?

Should I use the NDK? or should i compile it for ARM devices and then move it through adb?

Thanks

Comment: Please post questions relate to any programming issue you are facing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. You can use this [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) in order to be sure your question is not missing anything important.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to obtain pre-build binary or to compile iPerf3 for your Android device using SDK and NDK. You can follow the Dockerfile from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/KnightWhoSayNi/android-iperf), which contains all necessary steps to achieve it.